# How do I programmatically create an entity type from the install yml file?

Tags: entities, 9

I'm currently writing a module. In an update, I need to programmatically create a new entity type.

I have already created a suitable yml for installation. Like [this one](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21profiles%21standard%21config%21install%21node.type.article.yml/8.2.x), except it is not a Node Type entity, but a custom entity type entity.

For the sake of consistency, I'd like to use the yml directly in my updateN hook. Is there anyway I can simply use the config yml to create this new entity type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked file

*core/profiles/standard/config/install/node.type.article.yml*

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
name: Article
type: article
description: 'Use <em>articles</em> for time-sensitive content like news, press releases or blog posts.'
help: ''
new_revision: true
preview_mode: 1
display_submitted: true
```

is a content type and you can create it in code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType;

  $values = Yaml::parseFile('core/profiles/standard/config/install/node.type.article.yml');
  $bundle = NodeType::create($values);
  $bundle->save();
```

For a custom entity you find the label and the machine name of the bundle config entity in the entity class (Node.php in your example):

```
* @ContentEntityType(
*   id = "node",
*   bundle_label = @Translation("Content type"),
*   bundle_entity_type = "node_type",
```

The machine name is also the first part of the yml file name, replacing `_` with `.`